# What is the C++2014 equivalent of the C++2017 concept std::invoke_result_t?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

In my current project (Hardware Acceleration with Xilinx Vitis) I'm trying to include a header only Library which uses several C++2017 features. Xilinx Vitis however [does not allow C++2017 to be used](https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00006hpNCvSAM/how-to-use-c-17-standard-in-vitis?language=ja). Now since it is a header only library I tried to just create a local copy of it and replace all C++ 2017 Features with their C++ 2014 Equivalents. There are however 4 Lines in the Code which look like this:

```
using X = typename std::invoke_result_t<Fin, size_t>::first_type;
using Y = typename std::invoke_result_t<Fin, size_t>::second_type;
```

Now, the way I understood the documentation found [on Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) I figured that the correct way to rewrite these lines would look like this:

```
 using X = typename std::result_of_t<Fin>::first_type;
 using Y = typename std::result_of_t<Fin>::second_type;
```

However, this causes several (same) errors while compiling:

> /Workspace/PGM-index/include/pgm/piecewise_linear_model.hpp:333:49: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::result_of<pgm::PGMIndex<K, Epsilon, EpsilonRecursive, Floating>::build(RandomIt, RandomIt, size_t, size_t, std::vector<pgm::PGMIndex<K, Epsilon, EpsilonRecursive, Floating>::Segment>&, std::vector<long unsigned int, std::allocator >&) [with RandomIt = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator > >; K = int; long unsigned int Epsilon = 128; long unsigned int EpsilonRecursive = 4; Floating = float; size_t = long unsigned int]::<lambda(auto:8)> >’

So if anyone could help me understand how I would have to rephrase those lines to get the compilation to complete, I would be thankful. If there is any Information missing, please let me know.

Comment: its a trait not a concept

Comment: Looks like you dropped the `size_t` that's an argument supplied to callables of type `Fin`. I believe you're looking for `std::result_of_t<Fin(size_t)>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single parameter to `std::result_of_t` is a (very misleading<sup>1</sup>) function type. In your case it would be `std::result_of_t<Fin(size_t)>`.

1. That function type denotes a function that takes the arguments and returns the callable type that you are inspecting. For this reason it was deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20.

Comment: I think `Fin` is a functor type, which is being invoked with a `size_t` parameter. (Because if it were a return type, then you wouldn't need to write `std::invoke_result_t<Fin, size_t>` in the first place. You would just type `Fin`.) So you want `decltype(std::declval<Fin>()((size_t)0))`, You don't have to worry about the case where `Fin` is a pointer to member function because `size_t` has no member functions.)

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm commenting on the awkwardness of `std::result_of`, which abuses function types to shove everything into one template parameter